# Why does the shuffle' function require an Int parameter?

Tags: list, haskell, random, shuffle

In `System.Random.Shuffle`,

```
shuffle' :: RandomGen gen => [a] -> Int -> gen -> [a]
```

The [hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle-0.0.4/docs/System-Random-Shuffle.html) mentions this `Int` argument as

> ..., its length,...

However, it seems that a simple wrapper function like

```
shuffle'' x = shuffle' x (length x)
```

should've sufficed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`shuffle` operates by building a tree form of its input list, *including the tree size*. The `buildTree` function performs this task using [`Data.Function.fix`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:fix) in a manner I haven't quite wrapped my head around. Somehow (I think due to the recursion of `inner`, not the `fix` magic), it produces a balanced tree, which then has logarithmic lookup. Then it consumes this tree, rebuilding it for every extracted item. The advantage of the data structure would be that it only holds remaining items in an immutable form; lazy updates work for it. But the size of the tree is required data during the indexing, so there's no need to pass it separately to generate the indices used to build the permutation. `System.Random.Shuffle.shuffle` indeed has no random element - it is only a permutation function. `shuffle'` exists to feed it a random sequence, using its internal helper `rseq`. So the reason `shuffle'` takes a length argument appears to be because they didn't want it to touch the list argument at all; it's only passed into `shuffle`.

The task doesn't seem terribly suitable for singly linked lists in the first place. I'd probably consider using [VectorShuffling](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-shuffling) instead. And I'm baffled as to why `rseq` isn't among the exported functions, being the one that uses a random number generator to build a permutation... which in turn might have been better handled using [Data.Permute](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/permutation-0.5.0.5/docs/Data-Permute.html). Probably the reasons have to with history, such as Data.Permute being written later and System.Random.Shuffle being based on a paper on immutable random access queues.

[Data.Random.Extras](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-extras-0.19/docs/Data-Random-Extras.html#g:2) seems to have a more straight forward Seq-based shuffle function.

Comment: `inner` takes a list of nodes, and `join`s them into half as many nodes. That is, `[n1, n2, n3, n4 ...]` becomes `[join n1 n2, join n3 n4 ...]` (with slop at the end). `fix growLevel` simply frames this computation, repeating `inner` until everything boils down to one node. That's why it's called `growLevel`. We start with `n` height `1` nodes (`map Leaf`), then move to `n/2` height `2` nodes, then `n/4` height `3` nodes, until we get to `1 = n/(2^(h - 1))` node of height `h = log2(n) + 1` (disregarding aforementioned slop; please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I understand that, and that `fix` should reach this fixed point where there's no more than one entry somehow, but I haven't wrapped my head around how it actually works. It's like `head . head . dropWhile (\x -> length x > 1) $ iterate inner es`

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how the `fix` works. `fix growLevel` is `growLevel (growLevel (growLevel ...)) = \case { [node] -> node; l -> (\case { [node] -> node; l -> (...) (inner l)}) (inner l)`. The "data structure that contains itself" is not the list, it's the function. `let`ing the infinity away/inlining `fix` produces: `fix growLevel = let { function [node] = [node]; function l = function (inner l) } in function`. Honestly, I have no clue why `fix` was used. It's useful for inline recursive definitions, or to allow itself to be replaced, but the definition is neither inline nor public.

Comment: I understand what it does; the dropWhile method was just a way to accomplish the same result for this case. The nested calls are what `iterate` does. It's the particulars of how `fix` performs the test that have me puzzled, and your description might help with that if I mull it over.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a case when length of the given list is already known, and doesn't need to be calculated again. Thus, it might be considered as an optimisation.

Besides, in general, the resulting list doesn't need to have the same size as the original one. Thus, this argument could be used for setting this length.

This is true for the original idea of Oleg (source - http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/perfect-shuffle.txt):

```
-- examples

t1 = shuffle1 ['a','b','c','d','e'] [0,0,0,0]
-- "abcde"
-- Note, that rseq of all zeros leaves the sequence unperturbed.

t2 = shuffle1 ['a','b','c','d','e'] [4,3,2,1]
-- "edcba"
-- The rseq of (n-i | i<-[1..n-1]) reverses the original sequence of elements
```

However, it's not the same for the 'random-shuffle' package implementation:

```
> shuffle [0..10] [0,0,0,0]
[0,1,2,3random-shuffle.hs: [shuffle] called with lists of different lengths
```

I think it worth to follow-up with the packages maintainers in order to understand the contract of this function.

Comment: It also allows to shuffle only a prefix of the list which may be important for infinite lists.

Comment: It doesn't work with infinite lists, because the list is passed as is to `buildTree`. It might have if it used `take len elements`.